# In OS X programming, how to save and restore windows' orders?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am writing an OS X app, and the app can open multiple windows. Let's say it opens 5 windows.

(1) Save

When the app exits, the app tries to save each window's order by the `NSWindow`'s property `orderedIndex`.

Is it correct?

(2) Restore

When the app starts, it opens 5 windows and load the `orderedIndex` values for each window,

now how to set these 5 windows' orders?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it this way. Use the built-in API for state restoration as described in the [User Interface Preservation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW26) section of the Application Programming Guide.